# WordPress JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to achieve a custom option inside the "Publish Metabox" in WordPress admin custom post. And I want to know is there any native way to do expand/collapse divs (Check the below screenshot).

I wonder how WordPress itself achieves it like the below screenshot? (Maybe match the IDs like bootstrap JS libraries do ?).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to know is there any native way to do expand/collapse divs.

There is. Wordpress uses the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library on the admin side for interactive elements. In this case, it's just using a simple toggle effect.

> Display or hide the matched elements.

- Source @ https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p style="display:none;">Good Bye</p>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found it already. When I found I wondered why WP doesn't follow DRY principle and repeats the same toggle command, again and again by selecting elements with IDs. They could've done it better with a class name. ‍♂️

Comment: Keep in mind that WordPress need to support past version even from 10 years ago. Perennity is at the cost of flexibility.